# Ceph error when checking the status of the cluster

Tags: linux, centos, ceph

`ceph -s` error picture is as follows:

[image: ceph -s error picture]

In addition, I tried to execute the ceph-deploy admin xxNode command in the deployment directory, but the result was not satisfactory. I am not sure whether the directory I entered is the deployment directory.

The error code is as follows：

[image: ceph-deploy admin xxNode error picture]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Have you seen https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1501422?

Comment: `ceph-deploy` commands probably won't work since it doesn't have an admin keyring. Do you see in the command history what happened to the keyring? Do you have access to the MON nodes? If you're lucky they might have an admin keyring in `/etc/ceph/`, if that is the case, copy it to your ceph-deploy node, make sure the permissions are correct.

Comment: The key is that there is no ceph.client.admin.keyring key file in my /etc/ceph.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't find an admin keyring on any of the ceph nodes? That's bad, do you have a backup? You should be able to retrieve it with the mon keyring as well, I believe. Can you run `ceph auth ls` from a MON node?

Comment: Thanks everyone I have solved it.